# Run multiple IEDriver instances on the same machine?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I use a gem called parallel_tests to execute multiple instances of a browser to help run automated tests.  In Chrome and Firefox, it cuts down execution time dramatically.  I recommend it to anyone who hosts their UI tests on a single box.

In IEDriver, I can't seem to do this as I run into window focus problems.

Is there a way around this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [selenium wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#browser-focus) it's a known issue that is being considered but there really isn't a workaround other than using the remote driver and virtual machines each running their own instance of IE - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#multiple-instances-of-internetexplorerdriver